# 401 when authenticating with clickatel sms api

Tags: c#, clickatell

I am simply trying to send an sms using the clickatel API.

I have used the helper library found here:  https://github.com/clickatell/clickatell-csharp

```
 var apiClient = new RestClient(new RESTCredentials(ApiKey));                  
                    var result = apiClient.Authenticate();
                    Debug.Write("_apiClient.Authenticate() = " + result.Result);
```

and I get the following:

```
"Error occured during Clickatell Authenticate. Details: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

I have checked the api key several times, I have even regenerated a new on on their portal.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using the old Clickatell Csharp library that was written for the old endpoint.

You will need to use the new script which can be found at https://github.com/clickatell/Clickatell-Csharp-Platform

Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Link you pasted says that library is deprecated. Please use V2?

Comment: In future, please refrain from vague and prevaricate answers. You had over 10 answers that were all deleted. Answers are meant for actual answers to questions, not making assurances that you are forwarding the case to a call centre.